# How to ignore side-effect in Racket from using `set!`?

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

In [Exercise 35.4.2 from HtDP](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-44.html#node_chap_35), I've implemented the GUI and have a button called "Remove" which invokes a callback function. Here it is:

```
(define (cb-remove x)
  ((lambda (name result)
     (cond
       [(number? result) (remove-name name address-book)]
       [else (draw-message msg "Not found")]))
   (string->symbol (text-contents label-name))
   (lookup (string->symbol (text-contents label-name)) address-book)))
```

When I run this, I get the following message: `button-callback: result of type <Boolean> expected, your function produced #<set!-result>`. The problem is that I have to call `set!` in order to change the address book. However, the result of `set!` is `(void)`, which cannot cannot be combined with a Boolean type. How can I avert this problem? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
(begin (set! foo bar) #t)
```